# memory error while parsing\loading very large xml file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, out-of-memory

I got a large database in one xml file and I need to process the data in it (using python).

I tried to parse it with `xml` library using `xml.dom.minidom` and (in another script) `xml.etree.ElementTree` and then get deep tag by tag until the tag `<s>`, and then iterate over the tags I need (`<t>`) to retrieve the relevant data.

My problem is that the file is really large (217 MB) and I cannot parse or load it. I keep getting a memory error and it is not even loaded.

The structure of the file is this:

```
<corpus>

<head>
...
</head>

<body>
  <s id="s1">
    <graph>
      <terminals>
        <t id="s1_1" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
        <t id="s1_2" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
        <t id="s1_3" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
      </terminals>
    </graph>
  </s>

  <s id="s2">
    <graph>
      <terminals>
        <t id="s2_1" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
        <t id="s2_2" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
        <t id="s12_3" ex="bla" ex2="bla2"/>
      </terminals>
    </graph>
  </s>

.... # more than 50K <s> tags and almost 1M <t> tags

</body>

</corpus>
```

What I really need is to retrieve all the `<t/>` tags and to store the data of their attributes in a csv or something, but the computer cannot parse the large file.

I would be very happy to read your advice.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you parsing it?

Comment: See [using a sax parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263029/how-to-get-results-from-xml-sax-parser-in-python) or alternatively [pulldom](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipulldom/x-tipulldom-pdf.pdf).

Comment: @zvone I parsed it with the ```xml``` library. I added it now to the post (2nd paragraph). thanks for asking! @Justin Ezequiel I will try it. thanks!

Comment: Please show your code. Look also into `iterparse`. Quite a few online blogs and SO posts. Give it a try and come back with any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml library. pip install simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

doc = SimplifiedDoc()
doc.loadFile('test.xml', lineByline=True) # Read data line by line

for s in doc.getIterable('s'): 
    print (s.selects('t'))
```